# Show data on any number input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code that works for a pre-defined number (100200) but I would like to make it work for any random 6 digit number. The output remains the same.

I would like to show London, England as output in the given format when the user enters any 6 digit code from 000000 to 999999.

How do I got about this?

```js
const $main = $('#zipcode');
const $inputs = $('.location');
const values = {
  trigger: '100200',
  birds: ['London', 'England']
};
$main.on('keyup', function() {
  if (this.value === values.trigger) {
    $inputs.each(function(i, el) {
      el.value = values.birds[i];
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="zipcode" class="form-control" required>
<hr />
<input type="text" id="location1" class="location" required>
<input type="text" id="location2" class="location" required>
```

Comment: You would need to get the `values` object from an API containing `trigger` and `birds` for all of the 6 digit numbers you'd like to have and then loop through them using the same way, no?

Comment: This is just for a demo with no backend or API. Any number between 000000 to 999999 to show the given output would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to replace `this.value === values.trigger` with `this.value.toString().length === 6`

This will check if the number of inputs are equal to 6, without taking into consideration what the input actually is.

```js
const $main = $('#zipcode');
const $inputs = $('.location');
const values = {
  trigger: '100200',
  birds: ['London', 'England']
};
$main.on('keyup', function() {
  if (this.value.toString().length === 6) {
    $inputs.each(function(i, el) {
      el.value = values.birds[i];
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="zipcode" class="form-control" required>
<hr />
<input type="text" id="location1" class="location" required>
<input type="text" id="location2" class="location" required>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can check length of input value after trimming it (just to avoid extra spaces) and validate if input is an integer value.

```js
const $main = $('#zipcode');
const $inputs = $('.location');
const values = {
  trigger: '100200',
  birds: ['London', 'England']
};
$main.on('keyup', function() {
  var thisValue = (this.value).trim();
  if (thisValue.length == 6 && !isNaN(thisValue)) {
    $inputs.each(function(i, el) {
      el.value = values.birds[i];
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const $main = $('#zipcode');
const $inputs = $('.location');
const values = {
  trigger: '100200',
  birds: ['London', 'England']
};
$main.on('keyup', function() {
  if (this.value.length >= 6 && this.value >=0 && this.value <= 999999) {
    $inputs.each(function(i, el) {
      el.value = values.birds[i];
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="zipcode" class="form-control" required>
<hr />
<input type="text" id="location1" class="location" required>
<input type="text" id="location2" class="location" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

u can change the condition to

```
if (this.value.toString().length === 6)
```

it just checks if the number has 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your if condition =

```
if (this.value >= 0 || this.value <=999999) {
```

Comment: Cool. However, I want to have a minimum criteria of 6 digits before the results are declared. Thank You.

Comment: This is NOT what the OP wants. With this, if you write `0` you'll get the result, while he wants it to be minimum `000000`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
const $main = $('#zipcode');
const $inputs = $('.location');
const values = {
  trigger: '100200',
  birds: ['London', 'England']
};
$main.on('keyup', function() {
    if (Number.isInteger(this.value)) {
        if(this.value>=000000 && this.value<= 999999){
            $inputs.each(function(i, el) {
            el.value = values.birds[i];
            });
        }    
    }
});
```